# Error in XAML when setting the DataContext of View

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datacontext

I am getting a rather annoying error in the XAML editor that I can't get rid of. Maybe someone has also had the error and solved it.

The line local:DeviceViewModel/ is underlined with a blue wavy line. The error:
"An element with the same key has already been added".

The content of the window is displayed correctly in the WPF designer and the project can be compiled and there are no runtime errors.

The ViewModel is located directly in my namespace "PkaDeviceConfig".

In simplified form, my project consists of the DeviceView window which contains a user control that acts as a tab control and consists of 4 tab pages.
The content of each tab page is a separate user control.

In these 4 user controls I also had DeviceViewModel as DataContext and my guess was that this was the reason for the error.

After removing the DataContext, DeviceView was correctly displayed, compiled and executed but the annoying display of the error remained.

```
<Window x:Class="DeviceView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PkaDeviceConfig" 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:DeviceViewModel}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold"
    FontSize="14"
    Title="{Binding Path=AppTitle}"
    Width= "1502"
    Height= "928"
    >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:DeviceViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <local:DeviceDataTabCtrl Visibility="{Binding DeviceDataVisibility, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

<UserControl x:Class="DeviceDataTabCtrl">
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Device Data">
            <local:DeviceDataCtrl/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Order Data">
            <local:OrderDataCtrl/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Modules">
            <local:ModuleDataCtrl/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Processes">
            <local:ProcessDataCtrl/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="DeviceDataCtrl"/>
<UserControl x:Class="OrderDataCtrl"/>
<UserControl x:Class="ModuleDataCtrl"/>
<UserControl x:Class="ProcessDataCtrl"/>
```

Comment: Try: d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:DeviceViewModel}"

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio may also help.

Comment: Why would you set the design-time DataContext at all, when you also set the regular DataContext?

Comment: If I omit the design time datacontext, the design time window is no longer displayed in full. Instead, an another error message appears:
"The specified key was not given in the dictionary". The App is still compiling and running as expected.